# How can I resize my item's rectangle size using Qt model-view

Tags: qt, model-view

I wrote my own model sub-classing from `QAbstractItemModel`, and I am using `QTableView` class for viewing my model. Since the information which I am viewing is <= 2 symbols, I would like to know how can I resize my item's rectangle size.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options, in order from easier (but least flexible) to more complicated (but more flexible):

- Call `QTableView::resizeColumnsToContents` after your content is loaded. This may be good enough, and lets the user resize the column if he really wants to.
- Set the `ResizeMode` of the `QTableView::horizontalHeader()`. There are also a bunch of `resize*` methods to do this on-the-fly.
- Implement a custom delegate by deriving from `QStyledItemDelegate` and override the `sizeHint` method. This gives you absolute control. See ["Subclassing QStyledItemDelegate"](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyleditemdelegate.html#subclassing-qstyleditemdelegate).